# How can I increase my bike skill in GTA San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

In GTA San Andreas there is adriving school where I can increase my car skill but how can I increase my bike skill?

Comment: Are you talking about bicycles, or motorcycles?

Comment: I think they use the same skill. But specifically I am looking for motorcycles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the driving school, there's also a motorcycle school (and a boating school, and even flight school!).

The motorcycle school is unlocked after you're able to get to Las Venturas, and it's south of the stadium.  There should be an "S" icon on your map when it is available.

Comment: Or you just just ride a bike and get skill from that

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using schools, just drive for a long time without crashing. Also, bicycle skill and bike skill is different. Your cycling skill effects bicycles, while your bike skill effects motorbikes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a driving school at San Fierro near your Doherty garage and there is a bike school at Las Venturas. You can increase your skills there unless if you're still stuck at Los Santos.

If you mind changing some of the data in the game's files, go to the ar_stats.dat file inside the data folder of your main San Andreas directory and find the lines , which are these:

```
CODE
STAT_INC_MOTORBIKE_SKILL  25
STAT_TIMELIMIT_MOTORBIKE_SKILL  180
STAT_INC_DRIVING_SKILL  20
STAT_TIMELIMIT_DRIVING_SKILL  300
```

Now change the 180 to 1 and the 300 to 1 too. Save and load up your game. Get in any car and drive around. You'll instantly notice your stats rapidly rising. The same will happen for your Motorbike skill when you rid a motorcycle.

> This means that in normal gameplay time, 3 minutes of uninterrupted riding of a bike would increase the skill by 2.5%, while 5 minutes of uninterrupted driving of a car would raise the corresponding skill by 2%...

Answer (score -1):

I never bothered with the bike school missions. If you are willing to cheat, You can simply do it by entering the code on PC

- `NATURALTALENT`

But you have to use the cheat everytime you open a saved or new game.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to increase your bike skill. If you are willing to cheat, use `NINJATOWN` and steal the BF 400 bikes.

Comment: While this technically answers the question, I don't think the asker wanted cheats.